# Get link text from HTML using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

From the following example section of HTML I am pulling a bunch of football scores from a page using beautifilsoup, easy peasy:

```
<tr class='report' id='match-row-EFBO695086'> <td class='statistics show' title='Show latest      match stats'> <button>Show</button> </td>  <td class='match-competition'> Premier League  </td>  <td class='match-details
teams'> <p> <span class='team-home teams'> <a href='/sport/football/teams/manchester-city'>Man City</a> </span>   <span class='score'> <abbr title='Score'> 1-0 </abbr> </span>   <span class='team-away teams'> <a
href='/sport/football/teams/crystal-palace'>Crystal Palace</a> </span>   </p> </td> <td class="match-date"> Sat 28 Dec </td>   <td class='time'>  Full time  </td>   <td class='status'>    <a class='report'
href='/sport/football/25474625'>Report</a>
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import csv

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/teams/manchester-city/results/'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

for score in soup.findAll('abbr'):
    print(score.string)

*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
>>> 
None
1-2 
1-0 
0-2 
2-1 
2-2 
4-1 
0-2 
1-1
```

How do I extract the team names from this part of the HTML:

```
<span class='team-away teams'> <a href='/sport/football/teams/crystal-palace'>Crystal Palace</a>    </span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to first get the elements containing information about an each game - these are `tr` tags with a `class="report"`. For each row get the team names by class `team-home` and `team-away` and score by the tag name `abbr`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/teams/manchester-city/results/'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

for match in soup.select('table.table-stats tr.report'):
    team1 = match.find('span', class_='team-home')
    team2 = match.find('span', class_='team-away')
    score = match.abbr
    if not all((team1, team2, score)):
        continue

    print(team1.text, score.text, team2.text)
```

Prints:

```
Man City   1-2   CSKA 
Man City   1-0   Man Utd 
Man City   0-2   Newcastle 
West Ham   2-1   Man City 
...
```

FYI, `table.table-stats tr.report` is a [CSS Selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) that matches all `tr` tags with `class="report"` inside the `table` with `class="table-stats"`.

Comment: Fantastic explanation and example, it's so much easier to get your head round how it works when you see an example of the code whilst referring to the original HTML. Brilliant, thanks for this.